# Suppress smart contract console.log output

Tags: logs, unittesting, console

Is there a good, clean and easy way to suppress console.log() output from smart contracts without removing the log statements from the source code?

i.e. I don't want to see the smart contract log output when I'm running unit tests, but I usually do still when I'm running the run.js or deploy.js scripts. (I'm using hardhat and chai for testing)

Searching the web, I tried a few things things but they didn't work.

I've managed to do it by modifying a copy of hardhat/console.sol so it has an empty `_sendLogPayload` function and so doesn't output anything. I then change which one the contract imports depending on whether I want to see console output from the contract or not.
i.e. using the modified copy here

```
    //import "hardhat/console.sol";
    import "console.sol";    // the modified version
```

Just thinking there might be a better way of doing it, or a way to make my hack a bit slicker

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question I had modified a copy of console.sol file to prevent output, and imported that when I wanted to suppress console logging, but it was a bit hacky for my liking.

I've found it can be achieved with the a hardhat plugin, hardhat-preprocessor, which can be setup to filter out console.log and import lines in memory, but leave files intact. The behaviour can be toggled in hardhat-config.json

there's also another plug-in, hardhat-log-remover, which strips the console.log lines and import from the source files. Good to prep for prod deployment. hardhat-preprocessor has a command to create files with the lines striped too

Answer (score -1):

console.log is implemented by calling a mock contract created by hardhat. I suppose you can find it's address and replace it (e.g. removing its code) via overrides.

Comment: yes. that's along that lines of what I did